# .NET List<string> (call by reference?) with Dictionary objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list

I have the following code snippet:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> likeListDict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
List<string> lists = new List<string>();

lists.Add("hello");
lists.Add("world");

likeListDict.Add(1, lists);

lists.Clear();

lists.Add("foobar");

likeListDict.Add(2, lists);
```

At the likeListDict.Add(1, lists) part, the "hello" and "world" get added in to key 1. But once I do the lists.Clear(), and add in the key 2 to likeListDict, both key 1 and 2 now have "foobar".  How do I stop this (call by reference) and make it call by value?

Comment: Could u try it?  likeListDict.Add(1, lists);  lists = null; lists = new List<string>();

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no concept of "call by reference" or "call by value". `List<T>` is a reference type, so whatever you do to a given reference will be visible anywhere in the program where that reference exists.

What you want to do is create a new list instead of calling `lists.Clear();`

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> likeListDict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
List<string> lists = new List<string>();

lists.Add("hello");
lists.Add("world");

likeListDict.Add(1, lists);

lists = new List<string>();

lists.Add("foobar");

likeListDict.Add(2, lists);
```

Comment: cool this worked...i was close as i create a new list called templist but then did templist = lists and that was the same problem, cool thx

Comment: Small addition: there is of course *pass* by reference or value, which may be the source of the confusion about "call" by reference or value.  And of course that concept has nothing to do with reference types, either.

Comment: @phoog: True, but given that it has nothing to do with the problem at hand, I figured that it would be counterproductive to bring up

Answer (score 1):

Make a second list, don't try to reuse the first list. You're storing a reference to `lists` in the `Dictionary`, so adding it twice results in the same reference being in your dictionary twice, so changes to your list are reflected in both entries in the dictionary.

Ex:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var likeListDict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

        var lists = new List<string> {"hello", "world"};
        likeListDict.Add(1, lists);

        var secondList = new List<string> {"foobar"};
        likeListDict.Add(2, secondList); 

    }
```